# Are there additional buttons for ExoPlayer for Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exoplayer

Are there any additional libraries that contain button graphics for the Android ExoPlayer found [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/f8a8302f7bbcb47997095bd97b086eb633e49972/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.java). There are the options for fast forward, rewind, play, pause and a few others but there are no options for a mute/unmute or fast forward 2x/4x/etc. I want those options as I build an alternative UI.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Media Controller to provide the options that going to mute/unmute or fast forward. For adding these view(Buttons) in to the view of controller then for that customize the media controller. Check this also  [Custom Media Controller](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2668)

VideoControllerView

```
public class VideoControllerView extends FrameLayout {
private static final String TAG = "VideoControllerView";

private MediaPlayerControl mPlayer;
private Context mContext;
private ViewGroup mAnchor;
private View mRoot;
private ProgressBar mProgress;
private TextView mEndTime, mCurrentTime;
private boolean mShowing;
private boolean mDragging;
private static final int sDefaultTimeout = 3000;
private static final int FADE_OUT = 1;
private static final int SHOW_PROGRESS = 2;
private boolean mUseFastForward;
private boolean mFromXml;
private boolean mListenersSet;
private OnClickListener mNextListener;
StringBuilder mFormatBuilder;
Formatter mFormatter;
private ImageButton mPauseButton;
private ImageButton mVolumeButton;
private ImageButton mRewButton;
private ImageButton mSettingButton;
private Button mQualityButton;
private ImageButton mFullscreenButton;
private Handler mHandler = new MessageHandler(this);
private SeekBar seekbar;
private AudioManager audioManager;
private TextView txtVolume;

public VideoControllerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mRoot = null;
    mContext = context;
    mUseFastForward = true;
    mFromXml = true;

    Log.i(TAG, TAG);
}

public VideoControllerView(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mUseFastForward = useFastForward;

    Log.i(TAG, TAG);
}

public VideoControllerView(Context context) {
    this(context, true);

    Log.i(TAG, TAG);
}

@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
public void onFinishInflate() {
    if (mRoot != null)
        initControllerView(mRoot);
}

public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerControl player) {
    mPlayer = player;
    updatePausePlay();
    updateFullScreen(false);
}

/**
 * Set the view that acts as the anchor for the control view.
 * This can for example be a VideoView, or your Activity's main view.
 *
 * @param view The view to which to anchor the controller when it is visible.
 */
public void setAnchorView(ViewGroup view) {
    mAnchor = view;

    LayoutParams frameParams = new LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    removeAllViews();
    View v = makeControllerView();
    addView(v, frameParams);
}

/**
 * Create the view that holds the widgets that control playback.
 * Derived classes can override this to create their own.
 *
 * @return The controller view.
 * @hide This doesn't work as advertised
 */
protected View makeControllerView() {
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mRoot = inflate.inflate(R.layout.custom_media_controller, null);

    initControllerView(mRoot);

    return mRoot;
}

@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
private void initControllerView(View v) {
    mPauseButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    if (mPauseButton != null) {
        mPauseButton.requestFocus();
        mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(mPauseListener);
    }

    mFullscreenButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
    if (mFullscreenButton != null) {
        mFullscreenButton.requestFocus();
        mFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(mFullscreenListener);
    }

    mVolumeButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.volume);
    if (mVolumeButton != null) {
        mVolumeButton.setOnClickListener(mVolumeListener);
        if (!mFromXml) {
            //mVolumeButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    mRewButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rew);
    if (mRewButton != null) {
        mRewButton.setOnClickListener(mRewListener);
        if (!mFromXml) {
            mRewButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // By default these are hidden. They will be enabled when setPrevNextListeners() is called
    mSettingButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.settings);
    if (mSettingButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
        // mSettingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    mQualityButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.quality);
    if (mQualityButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
        //mQualityButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller_progress);
    if (mProgress != null) {
        if (mProgress instanceof SeekBar) {
            SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) mProgress;
            seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekListener);
        }
        mProgress.setMax(1000);
    }

    mEndTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
    mCurrentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_current);
    mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());

    installPrevNextListeners();
}

/**
 * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
 * automatically after 3 seconds of inactivity.
 */
public void show() {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
}

/**
 * Disable pause or seek buttons if the stream cannot be paused or seeked.
 * This requires the control interface to be a MediaPlayerControlExt
 */
private void disableUnsupportedButtons() {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (mPauseButton != null && !mPlayer.canPause()) {
            mPauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (mRewButton != null && !mPlayer.canSeekBackward()) {
            mRewButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (mVolumeButton != null && !mPlayer.canSeekForward()) {
            mVolumeButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } catch (IncompatibleClassChangeError ex) {
        // We were given an old version of the interface, that doesn't have
        // the canPause/canSeekXYZ methods. This is OK, it just means we
        // assume the media can be paused and seeked, and so we don't disable
        // the buttons.
    }
}

/**
 * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
 * automatically after 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.
 *
 * @param timeout The timeout in milliseconds. Use 0 to show
 *                the controller until hide() is called.
 */
public void show(int timeout) {
    if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
        setProgress();
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.requestFocus();
        }
        disableUnsupportedButtons();

        LayoutParams tlp = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.BOTTOM
        );

        mAnchor.addView(this, tlp);
        mShowing = true;
    }
    updatePausePlay();

    // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
    // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
    // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);

    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FADE_OUT);
    if (timeout != 0) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(FADE_OUT);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, timeout);
    }
}

public boolean isShowing() {
    return mShowing;
}

/**
 * Remove the controller from the screen.
 */
public void hide() {
    if (mAnchor == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        mAnchor.removeView(this);
        mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.w("MediaController", "already removed");
    }
    mShowing = false;
}

private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
    int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

    mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
    if (hours > 0) {
        return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
    } else {
        return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
    }
}

private int setProgress() {
    if (mPlayer == null || mDragging) {
        return 0;
    }

    int position = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    int duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
    //Log.d(TAG, "Duration->" + duration);
    //Log.d(TAG, "Duration Current->" + position);
    if (mProgress != null) {
        if (duration > 0) {
            // use long to avoid overflow
            long pos = 1000L * position / duration;
            mProgress.setProgress((int) pos);
        }
        int percent = mPlayer.getBufferPercentage();
        mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent * 10);
    }

    if (mEndTime != null)
        mEndTime.setText(stringForTime(duration));
    if (mCurrentTime != null)
        mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime(position));

    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        return true;
    }

    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    final boolean uniqueDown = event.getRepeatCount() == 0
            && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        if (uniqueDown) {
            doPauseResume();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
            if (mPauseButton != null) {
                mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY) {
        if (uniqueDown && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.start();
            updatePausePlay();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE) {
        if (uniqueDown && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            updatePausePlay();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE) {
        // don't show the controls for volume adjustment
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        if (uniqueDown) {
            hide();
        }
        return true;
    }

    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

private OnClickListener mPauseListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doPauseResume();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

private OnClickListener mQualityChangeListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mPlayer.updateVideoQuality();
    }
};
private OnClickListener mFullscreenListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doToggleFullscreen();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

public void updatePausePlay() {
    if (mRoot == null || mPauseButton == null || mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
    } else {
        mPauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
    }
}

public void updateFullScreen(boolean isFullScreen) {
    if (mRoot == null || mFullscreenButton == null || mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (isFullScreen) {
        mFullscreenButton.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_unstretch));
    } else {
        mFullscreenButton.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_stretch));
    }
}

private void doPauseResume() {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
    updatePausePlay();
}

private void doToggleFullscreen() {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (mPlayer.isFullScreen()) {
        mFullscreenButton.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_unstretch));
    } else {
        mFullscreenButton.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_stretch));
    }
    mPlayer.toggleFullScreen();

}

// There are two scenarios that can trigger the seekbar listener to trigger:
//
// The first is the user using the touchpad to adjust the posititon of the
// seekbar's thumb. In this case onStartTrackingTouch is called followed by
// a number of onProgressChanged notifications, concluded by onStopTrackingTouch.
// We're setting the field "mDragging" to true for the duration of the dragging
// session to avoid jumps in the position in case of ongoing playback.
//
// The second scenario involves the user operating the scroll ball, in this
// case there WON'T BE onStartTrackingTouch/onStopTrackingTouch notifications,
// we will simply apply the updated position without suspending regular updates.
private OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        show(3600000);

        mDragging = true;

        // By removing these pending progress messages we make sure
        // that a) we won't update the progress while the user adjusts
        // the seekbar and b) once the user is done dragging the thumb
        // we will post one of these messages to the queue again and
        // this ensures that there will be exactly one message queued up.
        mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromuser) {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!fromuser) {
            // We're not interested in programmatically generated changes to
            // the progress bar's position.
            return;
        }

        long duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
        long newposition = (duration * progress) / 1000L;
        mPlayer.seekTo((int) newposition);
        if (mCurrentTime != null)
            mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime((int) newposition));
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        mDragging = false;
        setProgress();
        updatePausePlay();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);

        // Ensure that progress is properly updated in the future,
        // the call to show() does not guarantee this because it is a
        // no-op if we are already showing.
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
    }
};

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    if (mPauseButton != null) {
        mPauseButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mVolumeButton != null) {
        mVolumeButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mRewButton != null) {
        mRewButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mSettingButton != null) {
        mSettingButton.setEnabled(enabled && mNextListener != null);
    }
    if (mQualityButton != null) {
        mQualityButton.setEnabled(enabled && mQualityChangeListener != null);
    }
    if (mProgress != null) {
        mProgress.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    disableUnsupportedButtons();
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
}

private OnClickListener mRewListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        pos -= 15000; // milliseconds
        mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
        setProgress();

        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

private OnClickListener mVolumeListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }
        showPopup(mContext);
    }
};

private void installPrevNextListeners() {
    if (mSettingButton != null) {
        mSettingButton.setOnClickListener(mNextListener);
        mSettingButton.setEnabled(mNextListener != null);
    }

    if (mQualityButton != null) {
        mQualityButton.setOnClickListener(mQualityChangeListener);
        mQualityButton.setEnabled(mQualityChangeListener != null);
    }
}

public void setPrevNextListeners(OnClickListener next, OnClickListener prev) {
    mNextListener = next;
    mQualityChangeListener = prev;
    mListenersSet = true;

    if (mRoot != null) {
        installPrevNextListeners();

        if (mSettingButton != null && !mFromXml) {
            mSettingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (mQualityButton != null && !mFromXml) {
            mQualityButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

public interface MediaPlayerControl {
    void start();

    void pause();

    int getDuration();

    int getCurrentPosition();

    void seekTo(int pos);

    boolean isPlaying();

    int getAudioSessionId();

    int getBufferPercentage();

    boolean canPause();

    boolean canSeekBackward();

    boolean canSeekForward();

    boolean isFullScreen();

    void toggleFullScreen();

    void updateVideoQuality();
}

private static class MessageHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<VideoControllerView> mView;

    MessageHandler(VideoControllerView view) {
        mView = new WeakReference<VideoControllerView>(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        VideoControllerView view = mView.get();
        if (view == null || view.mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }
        int pos;
        switch (msg.what) {
            case FADE_OUT:
                view.hide();
                break;
            case SHOW_PROGRESS:
                pos = view.setProgress();
                if (!view.mDragging && view.mShowing && view.mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    msg = obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
                    sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000 - (pos % 1000));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

// The method that displays the popup.
private void showPopup(final Context context) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

    // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_volumebar, viewGroup);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    txtVolume = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtPopupVolume);
    // Setting dialogview
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.END);

    window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.setTitle(null);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.setContentView(layout);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
    initControls();
}

private void initControls() {
    try {
        audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        seekbar.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        seekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        txtVolume.setText("" + audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
                txtVolume.setText("" + progress);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and custom_media_controller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@color/TvControllerBackground"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="4dip">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/quality"
        style="@style/MediaButton.Previous"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_5"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/size_5"
        android:text="@string/hd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rew"
        style="@style/MediaButton.Rew"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        style="@style/MediaButton.Play"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/volume"
        style="@style/MediaButton.Ffwd"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        style="@style/MediaButton.Setting"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
        style="@style/MediaButton.FullScreen"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_current"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mediacontroller_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light"
        android:thumb="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```